# Appending arrays on JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

Could any one tell me how to append arrays in an existing json data. I tried this code :

```
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $article = new ArticlesDevis();    
    foreach ($articlesDevis as $articleArray) {

                    $article = $articleArray;
                    $response->setData(array('image' => $article->getArticle()->getImage()->getId(),array('nom' => $article->getArticle()->getName())));

                }

                return $response;
```

but it returns only the last data from the `$articlesDevis` array

the $articlesDevis array contains 2 arrays (I can get the value of the null values) :

```
object(Proxies\__CG__\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article)[1695]
  public '__initializer__' => 
    object(Closure)[1761]
  public '__cloner__' => 
    object(Closure)[1760]
  public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
  private 'id' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => int 1
  private 'name' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'description' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'createdAt' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'prix' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'prixSolde' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'isSolde' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'percent' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'isVisible' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'enterprise' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'category' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'visit' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'image' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null

object(Proxies\__CG__\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article)[1693]
  public '__initializer__' => 
    object(Closure)[1761]
  public '__cloner__' => 
    object(Closure)[1760]
  public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
  private 'id' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => int 2
  private 'name' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'description' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'createdAt' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'prix' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'prixSolde' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'isSolde' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'percent' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'isVisible' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'enterprise' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'category' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'visit' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
  private 'image' (ArticleBundle\Entity\Article) => null
```

It returns only the last one which is id=2

```
{"id":2,"image":14,"0":{"nom":"Table"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess a solution

```
return new JsonResponse(array_map(function ($article) {
    return [
        'image' => $article->getArticle()->getImage()->getId(),
        'nom' => $article->getArticle()->getName()
    ];
}, $articlesDevis));
```